# Lightbox that pops up on page load with mapped image linked to two different webpages

Tags: javascript, image, popup, mapping, lightbox

I need a lightbox or popup image to have two different sections mapped out to two different external links, the popup needs to load when the page is opened. I'm not sure if this is possible, here is what I have so far.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/colorbox.css" />
```

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
<script>
  function openColorBox(){
    $.colorbox({iframe:true, width:"800", height:"400", href: "http://image.png"});//popup/lightbox image would go here, with two different sections of it clickable to links.

  }

         setTimeout(  openColorBox, 5000);
</script>
<style type="text/css">
#image-hotspot {
    background:url()
    height:285px;
    width:570px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}
#image-hotspot a#current {
    display:block;
    height:140px;
    width:585px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
}
#image-hotspot a#prospective {
    display:block;

    height:140px;
    width:585px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:140px;
}
   </style>
<div id="image-hotspot">

    <a id="current" href="https://google.com"></a> //sample links, will be directed to two different pages
    <a id="prospective" href="http://stackoverflow.com"></a>
     </div>
```